# Passing Arrays through intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a Double and a long array from one activity to another. I'm also passing a string.  The string is successfully passed but the arrays are not - its probably something simple but I just can't see it.

I move from one activity to another on the click of a button with the following code:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(stockDownload.this, StockDisplay.class);

                //need to find a way to access information referring to specific button - stock return and name
                ArrayList<Double> returnsforintent = (ArrayList<Double>) stockprices.get(view.getId());
                ArrayList<Long> errortrial = datesintent;
                Double[] returnstopass= returnsforintent.toArray(new Double[returnsforintent.size()]);
                Long[] datestopass = datesintent.toArray(new Long[datesintent.size()]);

                intent.putExtra(GRAPHRETURNS, returnstopass)
                ;

                intent.putExtra(GRAPHSTOCKS, stocks.get(view.getId()));
                intent.putExtra(GRAPHDATES, datestopass);
                startActivity(intent);
```

I use the following to receive the arrays and string:

```
            Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();


    double[] stockprice = intent.getDoubleArray(stockDownload.GRAPHRETURNS);
    long[] dates  = intent.getLongArray(stockDownload.GRAPHDATES);
    String stockname = intent.getString(stockDownload.GRAPHSTOCKS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use.

```
1. void putDoubleArray(String, double[]) //for passing array
2. double [] getDoubleArray(String) //for retriving array
```

in Bundle class.

Here in your case I think `double[]`*(Primitive type double)* and `Double[]`*(Object array)* is creating problem.(*Same thing for Long[] and long[]*)

**As method need parameter passed as `double[]` not `Double[]`**

Comment: Thanks.  It was the double vs Double distinction.  In the end i passed an ArrayList<Double> through the intent and then received it like this:ArrayList<Double> stockpricedownload = (ArrayList<Double>) intent.getSerializable(stockDownload.GRAPHRETURNS);